# Inserting related data from 3 different tables into one - in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think my problem is rather specific, so please let me know if I need to supply further information.

I have 5 different tables, 4 of which holds some existing data, and a 5. that needs data from the other 4.

The tables are structured in the following way:

BK-Data:

```
 - BK_ID
 - Supplier 1
 - Supplier 1 order no
 - Supplier 1 datasheet
 - Supplier 1 lead free /yes/no)
 - Supplier 2
 - ...
```

Supplier:

```
 - Supplier_ID (identity)
 - Name
```

Components:

```
 - BK_ID (PK)
```

Datasheets:

```
 - Datasheet_ID (identity)
 - Datasheet
```

ComponentSupplier:

```
 - Supplier_ID (Joint PK, FK from **Suppliers**)
 - BK_ID (Joint PK, FK from **Components**)
 - Order_ID
 - Datasheet_ID (FK from **Datasheets**)
 - Preferred (yes/no)
```

The table `BK-DATA` is from one database, while the remaining four tables is in another database.

Now, I want to fill the table `ComponentSupplier` with the data that exists in the other tables.

An example could be that this row from `BK-DATA`:

[image: BK-DATA row]

Becomes the following rows in `ComponentSupplier`:

[image: ComponentSupplier rows]

Where Supplier 1 will be the preferred supplier for the given component.

But, how do I do this? SQL Server does not know that the component with *BK_ID = x* have *supplier 1 = y* and *supplier 2 = z*.

I have thought of using conditional statements when using INSERT, but since the only table that knows the relationship between supplier, component, and so on is in one table, I'm at loss.

Can you give some help or advice?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help us help you. What you say at the moment isn't clear at all.

Comment: Not sure how to proceed with providing code help here but...you do NOT want to create a new table that contains copies of the data found in the other tables. This is what a view is designed for. You want to create a view that pulls all this data together for you. Then when the data changes you don't have to do anything, you just select from the view.

Comment: You say "the table BK-DATA is from one database, while the remaining four tables is in the same database." That's confusing. Why not just say all the tables are in the same database? Or just not even bother saying anything of the sort, since we would automatically assume that.

Comment: You also mention a "program" but provide no information about it. Are you using HLL to access the database and perform the inserts? Or are you referring to an MSSQL script?

Comment: Thank you for helping me clearify! I've edited my post to help clear up what I intend to do.

Comment: I don't see anything other than the addition of 2 hyperlinks, @Ioragi . If you're providing us with new information, it needs to be in your post, not somewhere *else*.

Comment: The information I've edited is indeed in the post. I've clearified that the tables are not all in the same database, specified which program I'm using, and, as you mentioned, added two hyperlinked pictures to illustrate what I intend to do.

Comment: You are going to need to create a script that `insert`s into `ComponentSupplier` by `select`ing data from a `join` across the other 4 tables. Do you know how to get started doing this?

Comment: images of data is nearly worthless. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) Honestly this would be pretty simple if you provide the details needed. But otherwise this is nearly impossible to answer.

Comment: I have experience working with insert and select, but not with a join. How can I get started on this? @robbpriestley

Comment: I'm unsure of what details that is needed - can you specify what details you need? @SeanLange

Comment: Here is the kind of thing you need. [mcve]

Comment: Arguably, teaching you how to `join` exceeds the scope of this forum as it is the subject of many readily-available tutorials. But, if we are to help you further, you're going to need to upgrade the quality of information you've provided. Please edit your post and instead of listing the columns of each of the 5 tables in an informal manner, provide the `create table` statements so we can see the specific names and types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with this code, which works for adding one supplier:

```
insert into CDB2020.dbo.ComponentSupplier
(
    Supplier_ID,
    BK_ID,
    Part_ID,
    Datasheet,
    LF,
    Preferred
)
select s.Supplier_ID, c.BK_ID, a.[Supplier 1 order no], a.[PDF Data 1 sheet link], a.[Supplier 1 LF], '1'
from  AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as c on c.BK_ID = a.[B-K no]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Suppliers as s on s.Name = a.[Supplier 1]
```